# Sessions and understanding how Rails knows the model to get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I've assigned `session[:active_company] = @company` in a method in my `companies_controller`

In my `application.html.erb` I have a line:

```
<li><%= link_to "Company", session[:active_company], :method => :get %></li>
```

When this is clicked Rails knows to use the `companies_controller` show method.

I'm reasonably new to Rails and this project is the first time I've added session variables myself so I've a couple of questions if anyone can help:

1. How does Rails know to use the `companies_controller`? Does it look at what's stored in the session and know that it is a @company so goes to the get method of that controller?
2. Are there pitfalls or security issues adding session data? Is there a better way to set the active_company?
3. Instead of storing the full company record in the session, should I just store the id then create a helper method to retrieve that company record? Does this slow the application down as it always has to perform a search?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

1) Rails is highly conventional. It knows that the session[:active_company] object is of type Company and by convention that model has a route like `/companies/{id of object}`. If you pass in an Object that isn't an Active Record Model you'll get an error and see that Rails is trying to call `model_name` on that object. So yea, your assumption is correct.

2) I don't think it's insecure at all. As long as your application is behind SSL then I don't see anyone doing a session hijacking or anything. In a similar application I just did the lookup for each request. The only thing I stored in the session was the user's id. Here's a guide that goes over the session and security.[Session Security in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

3) As long as your database is properly indexed doing the lookup every time won't hurt. Most databases have internal caching mechanisms to speed up repetitive lookups like that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Am loving Rails

Answer (score 1):

3)  You should store only the id in the `session` hash. Avoid storing entire objects in the `session`. Retrieve the company record using

```
  @active_company = Company.find( session[:active_company_id] )
```

2) Using session is a good way to keep track of things that are, well, session specific. However, storing the entire object in session *may* leave the object available in a cookie. (I'm not very sure about this though).

1) Rails takes the second argument in `link_to` to make a (magically good) guess at what you intended. When you pass it `session[:active_company]` which is a company object, it will set the path to `CompaniesController`, and the id of the object.  The results in a path of `/companies/:id`.

If you gave link_to an array of objects, no id will be pass in, resulting in `/companies`. By default, `link_to` are treated converted the verb GET.

In short, it should look like this:

`<%= link_to "Company", @active_company %>`